# How to add data to type List<List<Object>>

Tags: java, android, google-sheets-api

I am attempting to create an android app using android studio and I want to be able to upload data that the user inputs to google sheets.

I have looked over the google sheets API and I believe I have set up all the necessary dependencies correctly. The problem I am running into is adding data to the data type ValueRange using the built in method setValues().

The documentation says for ValueRange has the following method for setValues

```
public ValueRange setValues(java.util.List<java.util.List<java.lang.Object>> 
values)
```

And the google sheets API documentation gives the following example for how to use the setValues() method

```
List<List<Object>> values = Arrays.asList(
    Arrays.asList(
            // Cell values ...
    )
    // Additional rows ...
);
ValueRange body = new ValueRange()
    .setValues(values);
```

When I tried to add my own data I get the following error.

```
List<List<Object>> values = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("hello world"));

Incompatible types.
Required: List<java.util.List<java.lang.Object>>
Found: List<java.util.List<java.lang.String>
```

So my question is how do I add my data to type `List<List<Object>>` ?

Comment: I don't see any error for this line `List<List<Object>> values = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("hello world"));`

Comment: When you pass a string literal to the `.asList()` method, you're returned a list of Strings. If you need to have a list of Objects, declare the string literal as an object: `Object hello = "Hello World";
    Arrays.asList(hello);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast the string to Object:

```
Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList((Object) "Hello World"))
```

Or add a type witness:

```
Arrays.asList(Arrays.<Object>asList("Hello world"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Required is ArrayList of Objects but found ArrayList of Strings. Try the below code

```
List<Object> objects = Arrays.asList("Hello world");
List<List<Object>> values = new ArrayList<>();
values.add(objects);
setValues(values);
```

Comment: I get the same error
`error: incompatible types: List<String> cannot be converted to List<Object>`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
List<List<Object>> values = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"hello world"}));
```